# Trouble installing augustoroman/v8 with GO111MODULE=on

Tags: go

I was able to go through the whole process of setting up and installing github.com/augustoroman/v8 -- I built it's V8 dependency manually. When I run `go test` I get the following result:

```
PASS
ok      github.com/augustoroman/v8  9.433s
```

I installed the package at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/augustoroman/v8`. Everything seems to work well on OS X so far. However when I attempt importing with `import "github.com/augustoroman/v8"` in my own separate project I get a complaint.

Remembering back I realized that I have `GO111MODULE=on` enabled. This prompted me to add a go.mod with the following in the root of the v8 folder:

```
module github.com/augustoroman/v8
go 1.12
```

When I attempt running I get another error:

```
go: finding github.com/augustoroman/v8 latest
go: downloading github.com/augustoroman/v8 v8.0.0-20190418063024-4b66934a28a7
main.go:3:8: unknown import path "github.com/augustoroman/v8": cannot find module providing package github.com/augustoroman/v8
```

Basically it seems that the package works accordingly however either the GO111MODULE setting is messing it up or I've installed the package at an incorrect location. Tbh the GO111MODULE settings are doubly confusing on top of Go's already rigid setup/structure.

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When `GO111MODULE=on` is set, Go doesn't use `GOPATH/src` packages, rather, **it uses `$GOPATH/pkg/mod`.** (ref, [official blog](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules))

So, Installing changed package in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/augustoroman/v8` won't work.

As a workaround, you can use **[`replace`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive)** directive in `go.mod` file where this modified package is needed.

For, example, If you are using `github.com/augustoroman/v8` in `example.com/me/hello`  project, then use `replace` in `go.mod` file of `example.com/me/hello`.

It can be any of absolute or relative on-disk location,

```
module example.com/me/hello

require (
  github.com/me/some-repo v0.0.0
)

replace (
    github.com/augustoroman/v8 => /absolute/gopath/src/github.com/augustoroman/v8
)
```

or, even better (more idiomatic!), your fork repository in github.

```
module example.com/me/hello

require (
  github.com/me/some-repo v0.0.0
)

replace (
    github.com/augustoroman/v8 => github.com/me/v8
)
```

Comment: So you're saying that I need to fork the repo, use the replace command to rename it, to ensure that the go.mod file exists when the package is imported?

Comment: @ddibiase, I have updated my answer. It looks like, `replace` can be used for local disk's path too. It's good for debugging, but for idiomatic way, github fork is more preferred.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'd prefer to use the github method and stay idiomatic. I just created my fork and inserted the go.mod file https://github.com/ddibiase/v8/blob/master/go.mod however I'm getting this strange error go: github.com/ddibiase/v8@v8.0.0-20190519133706-5d6c14c5de84: parsing go.mod: go.mod:3: invalid module: github.com/augustoroman/v8 should be /v8, not v0 (v0.0.0)

Comment: I guess, the problem is, you need to use `replace` where this package/module is used. Not on this package itself.For, example, If you are using `augustoroman/v8` in `B` package/repo then use replace in go.mod file of `B` repo.

Comment: Now I'm super confused. I thought the idea was to fork and declare the mod so that when another module consumes the mod it knows how to replace the dependency paths?

Comment: No. The fork repo doesn't need to change anything. It's not confusing. Think this way, how would other repos know which github repo to use? So, the idea is, generally it will hit the actual github import path, but if you want to use another fork instead of the actual path, you need to add replace in mod file of that project. So, while compiling, it will know where to look. It all makes sense!! :)

Comment: Tahin unfortunately not yet.